# SQL Server nesting subquery performance?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am trying to evaluate and see what the best practice is to accomplish the following. I need to do 2 queries from the same tables only with different criteria, and then join them together with a unique ID. At the end, what I want to accomplish is getting all the records that exists in Query A but not Query B.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  Select 
    t1.ID from t1 
    Left Join t2 
    Left join t3 
  where 
    t1.field1 IN ('criteria 1', 'criteria 2')) QueryA
RIGHT JOIN 
(
  Select 
    t1.ID from t1 
    Left Join t2 
    Left join t3 
  where 
    t1.field1 IN ('criteria 3', 'criteria 4')) QueryB
ON QueryA.ID = QueryB.ID
WHERE QueryA is Null
```

Each QueryA and QueryB return about 2500 records, and took each less than 10 seconds . The result of the whole query returns about 30 records and over 3 minutes.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Instead of joining the queries and fetching the ones where it does not exist, you should do just the actual query and add there "and where not exists (Select 1 ...thequerywhichyoudontwanttobefound...)"

Comment: Hi there, the concept seems to make sense to me but I can't get it to work. If I understand correctly, it would mean that I would do the actual query pulling all the records that have all 4 criteria, putting that query at the FROM clause. Then, in the WHERE clause use NOT EXIST with the similar query specifying the other 2 criteria.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is checking all the ID that don't have all 4 criteria/activities associate. The goal is to make sure all the ID have all the 4 criteria. The query would help pull ID with either one of or a combination of criteria but not all. That way we can have a list of ID that we need to double check on. There are many different type of criteria/activities associate with an ID but I am only interested in the specific 4 criteria. Therefore, I have to first pull a query from 3 tables to get all the records with the 4 criteria and then do another filter. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Without the actual tables and row counts in them it's quite impossible to give suggestions, possibly a sqlfiddle example would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL's "except."  Do you need the joins to t2 and t3?  It looks like you're only filtering on and returning t1 columns.

```
Select ID from t1 where t1.Field in (criteria)
except
Select ID from t1 where t1.Field in (other criteria)
```

Comment: Hi, this method doesn't seem to work in my case because it seemed to return all the values from the first SELECT. And yes, I need some columns from t2 and t3. I didnt' put all the columns I need to simplify the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It shouldn't - it should return all the values from the first select that are NOT in the second select (unless there is no overlap between the two selects).  It will only work if you need the same columns in both fields - otherwise, you may need to do this on just the IDs, then use that as a subquery to return the rest of the columns you want.